# C++ templates with various types based on input

Tags: c++, templates

I know there are many questions about that issue but nothing seems to work for me or it's too complex for me to understand.
So I have template Node

```
template <typename T>
class Node {

public: 
    T value;
    Node* right;
    Node* left;
    Node(T value, Node<T>* right, Node<T>* left);
};
```

And Tree

```
template <typename T>
class Tree {

public:
    Node<T>* root;
    Tree();
    ~Tree() {}
    void insert(T value);
    Node<T>* search(T value, Node<T>* root) noexcept(false);
};
```

Now I want to create different Tree templates basing on what the user chose. Users can choose int, double, or string, these are the only options. I tried to use base class solution but my problem is that Tree uses type T in functions (and in Node) so I don't know how I should declare them in, let's call it BaseTree. Then I would be able to something like this:

```
BaseTree* tree;
tree = new Tree<int>();
```

I'm looking for a simple solution, I'm sort of beginner and it surprises me how this simple issue is so difficult for me to solve.

Comment: Your `Tree` type is templated by a type `T`, so any code that interacts with one should either specify `T` or be themselves templated by `T` and use `Tree<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to templatize the generic functions also. Let's say you have something like this in mind:

```
void traverse(BaseTree const& tree) noexcept {
    /* Logic here */
}
```

Instead, you do:

```
template<typename T>
void traverse(Tree<T> const& tree) noexcept {
    /* Logic here */
}
```

This also helps that you can use `Node<T>` to refer to the node instead of fabricating `BaseNode` and whatnot again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It helped me a lot, though I have another issuen now... In my BaseTree class I have ```template <typename T>
 Node<T>* search(T value, Node<T>* root) noexcept(false);```,  and when I try to call this function from main, like this `tree->search(10, tree->root)` it says root is not a member function of BaseTree but I can't add `Node<T>* root` there. I get ` data member ‘root’ cannot be a member template
  Node<T>* root;`. Do you have any idea if there's a way to fix this?

Comment: Okay, I sloved previous problem, now I get ` undefined reference to `void BaseTree::insert<int>(int)'`

Comment: @Awerde if you are declaring a member function, you don't have to template it. You don't even need the `root` argument: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/gCeF8e